# Loop through Javascript object and append key values to function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, object

I'm adding custom UI buttons to a CMS (via Tampermonkey) with respective click functions. Code is functional but I'm refining by converting the individual button elements to render the html based on an object's key/value pairs. That part works fine.

The issue: each button element has a separate click function that I want to consolidate into a single function and append the iterated object's values to based on the current key. Constantly hitting a wall when injecting the function. Thanks in advance.

New format with object

```
let campaignButtonsObj = [
{
name: 'tenZeroZero',
id: 'ten-zero-zero',
cta: '1000',
width:'45',
onclick: 'tenZeroZeroClick',
function: 'tenZeroZeroButtonClick',
searchQuery: '#10 #00 - 1000',
addFunction: 'addTenZeroZero',
clickValue: 'NEW1000'
},
{
name: 'twentyOnly',
id: 'twenty-only',
cta: '20', width: '35',
onclick: 'twentyClick',
function: 'twentyButtonClick',
searchQuery: '#20 - 20',
addFunction:'addTwentyOnly',
clickValue: 'NEW20'
}
];

const generatedHtml = Object.keys(campaignButtonsObj).reduce((accum, currKey) => accum + `<span class="sc-GQHCi fjxikX" style="display: block;"><button onclick="${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].onclick}()"class="sc-cUEOzv hEBGGF eEeywh" id="${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].id}" style="margin-right: 0.571429rem;background-color: rgb(36, 137, 169);color:#fff;border-radius:300px;border:none"><div style="height: 20px;width: ${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].width}px;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].cta}</div></button></span>`, '');

// need help here, this function returns an error
const buttonClick = Object.keys(campaignButtonsObj).reduce((accum, currKey) => accum + `function ${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].onclick}(){document.querySelector('[id="${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].id}"]').innerHTML = '${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].clickValue}';`, '');

const buttonAdd = Object.keys(campaignButtonsObj).reduce((accum, currKey) => accum + `function ${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].addFunction}(){document.querySelector('[id="new-button-container"]').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', ${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].name});document.getElementById("${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].id}").onclick = function() {${campaignButtonsObj[currKey].onclick}();};}`, '');

let newButtonContainer = '<div id="new-button-container" style="display:flex;align-items:center"></div>';
document.querySelector('[id="myDiv"]').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newButtonContainer);
document.querySelector('[id="new-button-container"]').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', generatedHtml);
```

---

Initial setup with separate elements & functions

```
let tenZeroZero = '<span class="sc-GQHCi fjxikX" style="display: block;"><button id="ten-zero-zero" class="sc-cUEOzv hEBGGF eEeywh" style="margin-right: 0.571429rem;background-color: rgb(36, 137, 169);color:#fff;border-radius:300px;border:none"><div style="height: 20px;width: 35px;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;">1000</div></button></span>';

let twentyOnly = '<span class="sc-GQHCi fjxikX" style="display: block;"><button id="twenty-only" class="sc-cUEOzv hEBGGF eEeywh" style="margin-right: 0.571429rem;background-color: rgb(36, 137, 169);color:#fff;border-radius:300px;border:none"><div style="height: 20px;width: 35px;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;white-space:pre">20</div></button></span>';


// want to append iterated objects values to this function
function tenZeroZeroClick() {
  var input = document.querySelector('[id="campaign-search-input"]');
  var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
  nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, '#10 #00 - 1000');
  var ev2 = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true
  });
  input.dispatchEvent(ev2);
}

function twentyClick() {
  var input = document.querySelector('[id="campaign-search-input"]');
  var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window.HTMLInputElement.prototype, "value").set;
  nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, '#20 - 20');
  var ev2 = new Event('input', {
    bubbles: true
  });
  input.dispatchEvent(ev2);
}

function addTenZeroZero() {
  document.querySelector('[id="new-button-container"]').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tenTwenty);
  document.getElementById("ten-zero-zero").onclick = function() {
    tenZeroZeroClick();
  };
}

function addTwentyOnly() {
  document.querySelector('[id="new-button-container"]').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', twentyOnly);
  document.getElementById("twenty-only").onclick = function() {
    twentyClick();
  };
}
```

Comment: You're missing `()` in the `onclick` attributes. `onclick="${campaignButtons[currKey].onclick}()"`. So it's not calling the function.

Comment: If you want a single function, give it a parameter that distinguishes the calls, and pass that as an argument.

Comment: @Barmar Good catch, added `()` to the `onclick` attributes. What parameter can I pass?

Comment: The key of the `campaignButtons` object?

Comment: @Barmar Tried passing the `campaignButtons` key, no luck there. Updated the code a bit, notably switching from an object of objects to an array of objects. The HTML structure still renders as-expected, only issue is that the functions render as strings vs actual functions. Here's the Codepen - https://codepen.io/mister-ant/pen/VwNaLyR?editors=1111

Comment: The codepen is missing the functions that the buttons call.

Comment: When I add the functions to the codepen, it calls them correctly. They get errors because there's no `campaign-search-input` element.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not a CodePen link. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.